# Should RegEx be stored in XML as CDATA or as Attributes?

Tags: asp.net, xml, regex, linq-to-xml

I am trying to output a `RegEx` in an xml file as an Attribute.

The problem is that the RegEx generated in the XML output is different than the one i have in Database:

```
-- database
[a-z0-9!#$%&amp;&apos;*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+(\.[a-z0-9!#$%&amp;&apos;*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@([a-z0-9_-]+\.)+(com|net|org|edu|int|mil|gov|arpa|biz|aero|name|coop|info|pro|museum|[a-z]{2})

-- generated
[a-z0-9!#$%&amp;amp;&amp;apos;*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+(\.[a-z0-9!#$%&amp;amp;&amp;apos;*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@([a-z0-9_-]+\.)+(com|net|org|edu|int|mil|gov|arpa|biz|aero|name|coop|info|pro|museum|[a-z]{2})
```

Should i save the RegEx as a `<![CDATA[ regex ]]>` or is this just the default behavior of xml files (encoding some characters and decode them automatically when i read it back) ?

This is the code i have to generate the element:

```
XElement attr =
    new XElement("Attribute",
        new XAttribute("RegEx", item.RegularExpression)
    );
```

And this is what it generates:

```
<Attribute RegEx="[a-z0-9!#$%&amp;amp;&amp;apos;*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+(\.[a-z0-9!#$%&amp;amp;&amp;apos;*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@([a-z0-9_-]+\.)+(com|net|org|edu|int|mil|gov|arpa|biz|aero|name|coop|info|pro|museum|[a-z]{2})" />
```

Comment: The fact that you want to export a regex, suggests that eventually, it is going to be imported - and executed. Please be aware that this is a potential ReDoS vulnerability: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReDoS

Comment: I had no idea about this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the regex in the database already uses XML escaping, and when copying it into the XML file, you have added another layer of escaping, so `&apos;` has become `&amp;apos;`.

There are two ways of escaping special characters, you can turn `&` into `&amp;` as done here, or you can wrap it in CDATA. In this case you don't want to do either, because it is already escaped.

I'm not familiar with link-to-xml so I don't know how to do this correctly in that environment.

Comment: I understand the problem now. I will keep them in CDATA just to be safe and to not alter the regex pattern at all. I am happy to get answers from an XML senior :)